# Is the orthogonal complement projector a projection operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, orthogonality

Let $X$ Hilbert space and $U \subset X$ convex closed. Then we can define the projection operator on $U$ $P \colon X \to X$ such that $P x \in U$ is the orthogonal projection of $x \in X$. Moreover $P$ is a self-adjoint nilpotent operator.

Now define $Q=I-P$ so that $Qx$ is the orthogonal complement of $Px$. Now by the fact that $P$ is a self-adjoint nilpotent operator we also have that $Q$ is a self-adjoint nilpotent operator.

Now every self-adjoint nilpotent operators are projection operators, is it correct? Then if this is true $Q$ is a projection operator on some set $Y$. Is it true that $Y=\overline{ U^C}$?

Comment: What do you mean by an orthogonal projection onto a closed convex subset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case $U$ is a closed subspace, and P is the orthogonal projection onto $U,$ then $(I - P)$ is the orthogonal projection onto the orthogonal complement of $U$ (which is closed, if this is how the question was about.)

I guess,  what you mean by "orthogonal projection" onto a closed convex set $U$ is the mapping which to every $x \in X$ assigns the unique $u \in U$ with $\lVert x - u \rVert = \inf_{v \in U}\lVert x - v \rVert$ - note however, that this mapping needs not be linear! For a simple example consider $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $U = [-1,1] \times \{0\}.$

Comment: Ok so what I need is for $U$ to be a closed subspace. In this case as you write $I-P$ is the orthogonal projection onto the orthogonal complement of $U$. But how do you see that this is closed?

Comment: $U^{\perp}$ is exactly the kernel of $P$ (and kernel of a continuous linear mapping is a closed subspace - as a preimage of a closed set, namelu of $\{0\},$ via a continuous mapping). To see this you may decompose $X = U \bigoplus U^{\perp}.$ Now, every $x \in X$ can be (uniquely) represented as $x = u+v, u \in U, v \in U^{\perp},$ and $P(x) = u$.

Comment: thanks clear, anyway why is it not common to call it "orthogonal projection" the mapping that to every $x$ assign a unique $u$ with $|x-u|=\inf_U |x-v|$ ? This is the projection theorem so should be the orthogonal projection, no?

Comment: In the definition of projection (in a vector space) one usually requires it to be a linear mapping.